# Finding if a given set of parentheses is valid or not

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is my code, it works for some strings but not for all.
Ex: "()()()()()((" expected is false, my code returns true.

```
function validParentheses(parens){
    var stack = [];

    parens.split('').map((cur, index) =>{
        if(stack.length === 0 || stack[index-1] === cur) stack.push(cur);
        else stack.pop();
  }); 

  return stack.length > 0 ?  false : true;
}
```

Comment: There must be something you can use here: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+validate+matching+parenthesis+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: `index` is going to be out of bounds for the stack once and element is popped.  Change it to `stack[stack.length - 1]`

Comment: The length will not be zero for the second `(` in `((`

Comment: Don't use `.map`, use `.forEach()`

Comment: I am confused with this use of .map() and .forEach()

Comment: `map()` is used for transforming elements into other elements.  You are not doing that here.  You are simply iterating.  So the usage of `map()` is misused.  `forEach()` is pure and simple iteration only

Comment: Simpler solution would be to count the number of opening and closing parenthesis and at the end return `openCount - closeCount == 0;`

Comment: @Yousaf `)))(((`

Comment: @Taplar depends on what OP wants. If the goal is to check if there's a corresponding closing parenthesis for each opening parenthesis, then counting the occurrences of each  set of parenthesis would be enough, irrespective of the order in which they are in the string.

Comment: Given that the logic is written to add one for opening and subtract one for closing, it isn't a large leap to assume the OP is wanting to validate that the `()` are paired.  But yes, if you want to be techincal about it, that has not been expressly said by the OP.  @katty Can you verify if that is your intent?

Comment: @Taplar the sequence does matter, not jus the number of opening closing parentheses

Comment: @katty I thought so.  However, to throw a bug into your logic, if I am reading it correctly, a string of `)()()()(` would evaluate to true.

Comment: yes this is true

Comment: A fix for that would be to check if the character is `)` and the length is 0.  If that is the case, stop your processing and just return false.

Answer (score 3):

`stack[index - 1]` will be valid so long as you push every iteration.  In the case that you pop an element, the incrementing index will always be out of bounds.

Change it to `stack.length - 1` to always get the last element, regardless of what is pushed or popped.

Answer (score 2):

For every '(' there must be a exactly one ')'. So you need a counter to see that there is an exact match

```
function validParentheses(parens){
   
   const chars = parens.split('');
   const numChars = chars.length;
   
   let ii;
   let numOpenParens = 0;
   for (ii = 0; ii < numChars; ii += 1) {
       curChar = chars[ii];
       numOpenParens += curChar == '(' ? 1 : -1;
       // return false if there is one too many closed parens
       if (numOpenParens < 0) {
          return false;
       } 
   }

   // return true only if all parens have been closed
   return numOpenParens === 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For case when stack's length is greater than 0:

- if top of the stack is equal to current iterated parenthesis, push that to stack
- else pop the stack

```js
function validParentheses(parens) {
  var stack = []

  parens.split("").forEach((cur) => {
    if (stack.length > 0) {
      if (stack[stack.length - 1] === cur) {
        stack.push(cur)
      } else {
        stack.pop()
      }
    } else {
      stack.push(cur)
    }
  })

  return stack.length > 0 ? false : true
}

console.log(validParentheses("()()()()()(("))
console.log(validParentheses("()()()()()()"))
console.log(validParentheses("((()))"))
console.log(validParentheses("((())))"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the last added value as well, because an unresolves closing bracket should remain in he stack.

BTW, [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is the method of choice, because [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array, which is not used here.

```js
function validParentheses(parens) {
    var stack = [];

    parens.split('').forEach((cur, index) => {
        if (cur === ')' && stack[stack.length - 1] === '(') stack.pop();
        else stack.push(cur);
    });

    return !stack.length;
}

console.log(validParentheses("(())()"));
console.log(validParentheses("()()()()()(("));
console.log(validParentheses("))(())"));
```

Comment: i dont think hardcoding the parentheses is a good idea!!

Answer (score 1):

in `stack[index-1] === cur`
you are comparing if the char isn't the same like the one stored in the stack, so )( opposite parens will be valid

you can try do something like this

```
function validParentheses(parens) {
    if (parens % 2 == 1) return false;
    for (let i = 0; i < parens.length; i++) {
        const char = parens[i];
        if (char == "(") {
            if (parens[i + 1] == ")") {

                i++;
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```